# MySQL error 111 (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x')

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server

I have MySQL running on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I'm trying to connect to it with an external connection but am getting met with error 111 (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x'). I know this is supposed to be a refusal, and I found other threads that say to comment (or change) the bind-address line in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`, however doing so made no difference for me. I don't know what I'm missing here. I have tried to make new users and try again but I don't think that will aid the issue seeing as its a straight up connection refusal.

Here is my full `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
datadir = /var/lib/mysql


# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
# tmpdir        = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
# bind-address       = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
# max_allowed_packet    = 64M
# thread_stack      = 256K

# thread_cache_size       = -1

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

# max_connections        = 151

# table_open_cache       = 4000

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
#
# Log all queries
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
# general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
# slow_query_log        = 1
# slow_query_log_file   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
# long_query_time = 2
# log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
# server-id     = 1
# log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
# binlog_do_db      = include_database_name
# binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name
```

As you can see, not only is `bind-address` commented out, but I also tried setting it to `0.0.0.0` before doing so. Is there anything else I can check? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you can connect from your local machine? Your local network? But not from outside your network? Any firewall in between your local and external network? You have a router inbetween? Is it forwarding the port? Does your internet provider lock the port? Are you using the correct external ip?

Comment: @derpirscher I can connect remotely via SSH from my PC at home with no issue (the server is from Vultr, based in New Jersey). I got MySQL set up and set up a couple of users. There are firewall settings available, so I have it set to accept everything from port 3306 anywhere (0.0.0.0). I restarted both MySQL and the server itself with no luck.

Comment: Do you have a webserver on that machine you are able to access from external? If yes, you could try stopping mysql and setup the webserver to additionally listen to port 3306. If you are able to connect to your webserver on port 3306 there is an issue with your mysql configuation. If you can't, the issue is probably in your network config

Comment: You can also execute `netstat -lnp | grep mysql` on your server after you start mysql. This should list the addresses mysql is listening to

Comment: @derpirscher I tried the netstat command provided and it looked like 3306 was opened to everything so I was stumped. Something must have been wrong the first time I set it up however as I ended up getting it working by reinstalling the server, reinstalling MySQL and commenting out bind-address once again and it seemed to work. I'd done this multiple times but this time it decided to work. :) Thank you for the help I truly appreciate it.